# Finding the initial values $x_o$ such that Newton's iteration converges for $(x-a)^2=0$

Tags: numerical-methods

For $f(x) = (x - a)^2$ where $a$ is a constant, how would I determine the value of $x_0$ so that Newton's iteration (searching for the root of $(x-a)^2=0$) converges?

Using Newton's Iteration root finding, I got $x_{k+1} = \frac{x_k+a}{2}$.

What would I have to do next? The hint I was given was to use contraction mapping theorem but I wasn't sure how to apply it. I thought that using the convergence property $\vert g^\prime(x)\vert<1$ was enough to explain this question. For instance, $g(x) = x + f(x)$ then $g^\prime(x) = 2(x-a)$. So when $x > a$ it converges... Help is appreciated.

Comment: What is the equation you are trying to solve? Usually Newton-Raphson iteration is used where you are solving $f(x)=0$ but that would be trivial in your case. Anyway, the choice of $x_0$ is almost immaterial as the method usually converges so rapidly.

Comment: Got something from the answer below?

Answer (score 0):

You got
$$
x_{n+1}-a=\frac{x_n-a}2
$$
thus you get linear convergence towards $a$ for any initial value $x_0$.